# Blank page when PHP alert is shown

Tags: php, alert

To indicate whether a form submission went through or not, I created an alert. It's working, but the alert is shown on a blank page.

I tried to solve it via a header refresh, but only after the alert is shown on the blank page, the user gets redirected to the homepage. Any ideas how to solve the blank page from appearing?

See the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['button'])){
    $data = array(
        'organization' => $_POST['organization'],
        'description' => $_POST['description'],
        'website' => $_POST['website'],
        'facebook' => $_POST['facebook'],
        'instagram' => $_POST['instagram'],
        'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
    );
    $table_name = 'organizations';

    $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data, $format=NULL);

    if ($result==1) {
        echo "<script>alert('Organizations saved');</script>";
    }
    else {
        header("refresh: 0; url=/");
        echo "<script>alert('Unable to save organization');</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: The alert pauses all the other actions of the page i think including honouring the refresh header. Anyway your page contains nothing except the alert as far as I can see, so it's unclear what else you're expecting to see on it? Are you intending that the alert should be shown _after_ the redirect happens? In that case the alert needs to be in the page where the redirection goes to

Comment: P.s. an alert is not actually very user friendly for this, because it makes everything else inaccessible and also once the message is dismissed the user can't get back to it. I would just echo some html into the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, one of the ways is to trigger the alert on the redirected page (in your case, the home page)

Step 1: Enable session

Since I believe you are using wordpress, add the following line to the top of your functions.php

```
if ( !session_id() )
add_action( 'init', 'session_start' );
```

Step 2: amend the db insertion php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['button'])){
...... 

    if ($result==1) {
$_SESSION["message"]="Organizations saved";
header("refresh: 0; url=/");
    }  else {
$_SESSION["message"]="Unable to save organization";
        header("refresh: 0; url=/");
    }
}
?>
```

Step 3: add a few lines at the bottom of the homepage:

```
<?php
session_start();

.... other statements

?>

<?php 
if ($_SESSION["message"] !="") { ?>

<script>
alert('<?php echo $_SESSION["message"]; ?>');
</script>

<?php 
// clear the session so that reload will not cause another alert
$_SESSION["message"] ="";
} ?>
```